# How to simplify tic tac toe winner checking

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm programming a tic tac toe game in java and I'm not sure if there is a much faster/ easier way to check for a winner.

```
if ( boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[0][1] && boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[0][2]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[0][0]);
    } else if ( boardArray[1][0] == boardArray[1][1] && boardArray[1][0] == boardArray[1][2]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[1][0]);
    } else if ( boardArray[2][0] == boardArray[2][1] && boardArray[2][0] == boardArray[2][2]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[2][0]);
    } else if ( boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[1][0] && boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[2][0]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[0][0]);
    }else if ( boardArray[0][1] == boardArray[1][1] && boardArray[0][1] == boardArray[2][1]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[0][1]);
    } else if ( boardArray[0][2] == boardArray[1][2] && boardArray[0][2] == boardArray[2][2]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[0][2]);
    } else if ( boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[1][1] && boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[2][2]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[0][0]);
    } else if ( boardArray[0][2] == boardArray[1][1] && boardArray[0][2] == boardArray[2][0]) {
        System.out.println("The wimmer is: " + boardArray[1][1]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("ITS A DRAW");
    }
```

I'm aware that I could use a for loop to loop through the different indexes but this only reduces the lines of code by about 2/3 so doesn't make a huge difference

Comment: "reduce by 2/3" is alot, should we worth it. The main benefit and reason why you should use a loop is DRY: Don't repeat yourself. You actually gave a good example: You have a typo: "The wiMMer is:". Now you have to change 8 lines instead of only one. Simplifying the code will make it a lot easier to change things, be it correcting an error or changing some behavior.

Comment: ^ that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Sentry you're right and I've changed my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm aware that I could use a for loop to loop through the different indexes but this only reduces the lines of code by about 2/3 so doesn't make a huge difference.

You can go ahead to use loops to improve your code because it not only cut down the number of lines of code, it also gives you a ton of benefits. It improves your:

- **Maintainability**

  To edit the code, you just have to edit it once instead of editing it n times, where n is the number of iterations it supposed to go through.
- **Scalability**

  This may not be a good example, but imagine you want to change the board to 4 x 4. With loops, you probably just  need to update the board size. All other codes can almost be left untouched.
- **Readability**

  One instance of the code will be easier to read than multiple repeated lines.
- **Reduce chances for typo errors**

  Lesser code, lesser chance for typographical errors.
- **Makes debugging easier**

  Error finding and debugging will actually be easier due to improved readability.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to go through if else statement for the first 6 parts. You can use loop for it. It will make your code compact.

```
public static void check(int[][] boardArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (boardArray[i][0] == boardArray[i][1] && boardArray[i][0] == boardArray[i][2]) {
            System.out.println("The winner is: " + boardArray[i][0]);
            return;
        } else if (boardArray[0][i] == boardArray[1][i] && boardArray[0][i] == boardArray[2][i]) {
            System.out.printf("The winner is: " + boardArray[0][i]);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[1][1] && boardArray[0][0] == boardArray[2][2]) {
        System.out.println("The winner is: " + boardArray[0][0]);
    } else if (boardArray[0][2] == boardArray[1][1] && boardArray[0][2] == boardArray[2][0]) {
        System.out.println("The winner is: " + boardArray[1][1]);
    } else {
        System.out.println("ITS A DRAW");
    }
}
```